# Jquery load() a html file which contains JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a big dilema. I want to load a `.html` file which contains javascript(google maps) code to render the div inside it.

maps.html look like this :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }

    return vars;
}
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[




var hash = getUrlVars();

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(hash['lat'],hash['lng']),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


      downloadUrl("xmlout_carol.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length+1; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("nume");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("adresa");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<font face='Tahoma' style='font-size:12px;'><div style='min-width:230px;'><b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address +"<a target='_top'  href='../statii.php?id=" + type + "'><img style='float:right; border:0px; margin-left: 40px;'  src='go.png' /></a><div/></font>";
          var tip = markers[i].getAttribute("tip");
          var icon = customIcons[tip] || {};

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
           // shadow: 'shaddow.png'
          //shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.close(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>

  </script>

  <body onload="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
```

this script render the map to the `div.map`

What i want to do is to load this `.html` into a div that is contained in another `.php` file like this :

```
$("div#insert_here").load("maps.html?lat=xxx&long=yyy");
```

It output the div contained in maps.html but with no map no java.

So the question is... How do I load a `.html` file using jquery in another `.php` file if the `.html` file already contains javascripts to output data to the `div` in `.html` file ???

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Nothing in your code suggests you're using jQuery, only the last part of your question... Have you looked at [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) at all?

Comment: And this is just another reason why it's bad to have JavaScript code mixed with markup.

Comment: This is what google is doing to display maps on your site. And i have already tried `$.get('maps.html?lat=xxx&long=yyy', function(data) {
    $("div#mapa_google").html(data); });` and not working.

Comment: How do i send GET variables or any variable to an external `.js` file using jquery`s `getScript()` ??

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading a file which has both HTML and JavaScript in it, can you load the JavaScript with the page initially, make an ajax call for the HTML, and call the JavaScript once the ajax request is complete? This will solve a lot of headaches with this issue.

Comment: Look i have quite a lot of files ... I thought of that but the question is why this won't work with juqery`s `.load()` or `.get()` functions native.

Comment: `load` and `get` and don't evaluate JS, only `getScript` and `getJSON` will (I think). You are essentially just inserting ineffective markup.

Comment: and because i have GET variables sent to that page .. how will i send 2 variables to that `.js` file ? (using `$.getScript("maps/google_statii.js", function(){
    load();
    
  });`

Answer (score 1):

As the others said, load JS particularly, or do the eval() function ;).

That parses the JS and makes it possible to be executed initially.

Answer (score 0):

I dont use load and get much it almost always seems better to use $.ajax or $.post (more flexibility, I also suggest calling json and using the dataType:"json". Again more flexible).

Use callbacks after success to run the javascript you need once the ajaxed html is loaded into the page. You call use beforeSend to load script you need (although unless there is a good reason just add those scripts to the page along with everything else (more robust/cacheable)).

If google_statii.js needs dynamic variables one way would be use hidden inputs on the page with values populated server side and then call them within the script.

ie. var x = $("input#myHiddenVariable");