# How to include a common file which loads many javascripts into the header of an HTML file

Tags: javascript, header

I tried many ways, and can't figure how to do this.

I am loading number of external scripts in the header of many html files. Here is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({  tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript" 
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/plugin/v2.1/cdfplugin.js"></script>
```

What is the best way to avoid having to copy and paste these again and again in each HTML file?

I could not put all of these in one common.js file and include that, since these already have `<script>` in them. i.e. I can't do this

```
<script src="common.js"></script>
```

Any idea how to do this? may be with jquery? (I know nothing about it). May be this is related? [Jquery load() a html file which contains JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668219/jquery-load-a-html-file-which-contains-javascript)

thanks

Comment: Please check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/950087/1169519).

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following commands multiple times in your common.js for each source you want to load. Just keep changing the `node.src` value.

```
    var node = document.createElement('script');
    node.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(node);
```

And you can choose where to add your script in `body` i.e. `document.body.appendChild(node);` or `head` i.e `document.head.appendChild(node);` of html

Comment: am not sure what you mean by "pull in the content of an external file and paste that at the point where the include command is"? your question mentioned including all the scripts as a common file, so now you can write common.js once and include it in any of the html pages and all your scripts will be loaded

Comment: use `node.type` to include your type parameter and I believe using `node.nodeValue` will include the content of that node